# How to change the arc angle of a circular sector?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I am able to easily draw single circular sectors using a newcommand such as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*{\eAngle}[2]{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline=-0.65ex]
       \node[circular sector, fill=#1, rotate=#2, minimum size=0.1cm] at (0,0) {};
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \eAngle{red}{45} 
\end{document}
```

This lets me set the color and rotation of the sector. These get inserted into paragraphs eg

```
This is an angle: \eAngle{red}{45}
```

I should add, I don't care how its done, I happen to use circular sector shape as I thought that would be the thing to use. But any other solution would be acceptable.

Using the circular sector shape I can't figure out how to change the arc width of the sector. I thought I could use the key, circular sector angle but that also appears change the size of the sector by making it longer as the angles gets smaller. The desired effect is shown in the figure below, same radius but different angle:

[image]

any suggestions on how to do this?

Here is another example using the command above. The rotation orientation is unchanged at zero (second argument) but the angle at the tip (third argument) is progressively increased:

```
  Here is a pie \eAngle{red}{0}{10}, \eAngle{red}{0}{20}, \eAngle{red}{0}{40}, \eAngle{red}{0}{60}, \eAngle{red}{0}{80}
```

This yields the following image. Note, as the angle gets bigger at the tip the sector radius gets shorter (left to right). I'd like to have a fixed radius as the angle is changed.

The following is not what I want, I want a fixed radius (what looks like the length in the images below)

[image]

Comment: Do you need this to actually be a node? You can just draw a circular sector as a normal path. The `inner sep`s might interfere with the size of the node.

Comment: I don't mind how it's drawn so long as I can rotate it easily around the center (center of the image not eg the point of the sector) to get different orientations but also different angles at the point (but same radius)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  @circular sector/radius/.initial=1,
  @circular sector/tip/.initial=0,    % where the tip points to (i.e. the rotation)
  @circular sector/angle/.initial=90, % the opening of the sector
  @circular sector/.search also=/tikz,
  @circular sector/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/@circular sector}{#1},
  circular sector/.style={
    @circular sector={#1},
    rotate=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@circular sector/tip},
    insert path={
      \pgfextra{% values we need more than once
        \pgfmathsetmacro\halfAng{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@circular sector/angle})/2}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/@circular sector/radius}}}
      (0:{2*\radius*sin(\halfAng)/(3*rad(\halfAng))}) -- +(180-\halfAng:\radius)
      arc[start angle=180-\halfAng, end angle=180+\halfAng, radius=\radius]
      -- cycle}}}
\newcommand*\eAngle[1][]{% \fontdimen22\textfont2 is “vertical center”
                         % this puts the center of the sector in the “middle”
  \tikz[baseline=+-\fontdimen22\textfont2]\fill[circular sector={#1}];}
\begin{document}
Points to $ 30^\circ$ with angle of $10^\circ$: \eAngle[red, tip=30, angle=10]

Points to $250^\circ$ with angle of $45^\circ$:
                                   \eAngle[blue, tip=250, angle=45, radius=.7]

\foreach[evaluate={\c=\ang/3.6;}] \ang in {0, 10, ..., 359}{
  \eAngle[red!\c!blue, angle=30, tip=\ang]}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I confirm this works. I'm am surprised it was this involved. Much obliged for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

with this code (adapted from your's one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}

\newcommand*{\eAngle}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline=-0.65ex]
        \node[circular sector,circular sector angle=#3, fill=#1, text=white, rotate=#2, minimum size=.1cm] at (0,0) {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \eAngle{red}{0}{30}{Testo}  \eAngle{brown}{135}{90}{20\%} \eAngle{cyan}{90}{20}{Testo di prova}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: Changes in code:

```
\begin{document}
    \eAngle{red}{0}{20}{\hspace*{1cm}}  \eAngle{brown}{135}{90}{\;\;\;} \eAngle{cyan}{0}{120}{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But the radius of the sector changes as the angle at the tip changes. I need the sector radius to stay fixed  This is true even if I don't include the text you added.

Comment: @rhody I have changed the radius of sector depending of the text inside; plus i changed also di angle. The radius change, starting from a minimum, only with the length of the text inside.

Comment: In your example I need to remove the text because there won't be any text in the sectors when I draw them. Plus the text in this case is changing the radius of the sectors.  However it I run the code without the text, the blue sector has a larger radius (tip to curved end) than the red sector and the brown sector has a smaller radius (tip to curved end) then the red sector.  I need the sectors to have the same tip to curve length even though the tip angles are different.

Comment: I bad approach I came up with is to store the images as small pdf files and use \rotatebox and \includegraphics to draw the shapes. But this is far from idea, as I'd have to store multiple pdfs for each color and each tip angle I need to use.

Comment: @rhody I dont understand what exactly You want. If You dont want to up vote and/or accept my answer no problem...

Comment: What I want is not given by your answer. Maybe I wasn't very clear, I apologise. If you take a measuring ruler and measure the length of your blue sector from tip to round end it is longer than the red sector length from the tip to round end. I want them to the the same length.

Comment: @rhody If you want to change the radius without text put inside {} dummy text: \; or also \hspace*{.5cm},.... It works! See my ADDENDUM in my answer.

Comment: if you look carefully at the blue sector you have, it is longer from tip to round end compared to the red sector even if you remove the text. What I would recommend is you redraw your figure without the text, I think then you will l see the radii are different.

Comment: Raffaele, could you update your answer to what you think is correct then I can try it out. Note, don't add any text, I have no text inside the sector in my original question.

Comment: I'll try your addendum.

Comment: I tried the addendum, unfortunately the sectors are not the same size. The red sector is 2.5 cm from tip to curve end, brown sector 1 cm and red blue sector 0.9 cm.  I zoomed in to make these measurements. My objective is to draw sectors that have the same size but different angles at the tip.  Maybe its impossible to do with the circular shape.

Comment: The addendum still has different content, only now it's different whitespace instead of text.  Try "\eAngle{red}{0}{20}{\hspace*{1cm}}  \eAngle{brown}{135}{90}{\hspace*{1cm}} \eAngle{cyan}{0}{120}{\hspace*{1cm}}", it may be closer to what you want.